# Transition not working properly when unfocusing

Tags: html, css

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RYxXbY), the transition works fine when unfocusing.

but [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gdoVpq), it doesn't work. When I click outside the element to unfocus, the label will go down right away without transitíon, which I don't want.

I use this same code for both:

```
transition: top .5s ease, font-size .5s ease;
```

Comment: Hi there, in what way is the transition not working? Without knowing what the issue is, we cannot provide an answer. Additionally, what have you attempted to fix the issue?

Comment: "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details" — Try creating a smaller [mcve] or providing more detail.

Comment: I can't see what's wrong. The transitions appear to work ok in both cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although that one line is the same (`transition: top .5s ease, font-size .5s ease;`), the rest of the CSS is different, and that's why they don't work the same.

For example, the one that doesn't work applies styles to generic `span` elements, which the working one doesn't. The working one applies styles to `.user-input + .user-label, .pass-input + .pass-label { ... }` which the broken one doesn't.

Considering one works how you want and the other doesn't, it makes sense to use the CSS from the first! Literally copied and pasted CSS from one pen to the other: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LJQPap

Or, fixing the broken pen by removing the CSS affecting the `span` and add the parts that were missing: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PdQYXK

As a side note, there's a lot of noise in the CSS, which is probably what makes it hard to debug.  Cleaning it all out to the simplest version of the problem makes it a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using this piece of code

input:focus + label > span, 
input:valid + label > span

```
{
  top: -20px; 
  font-size: 15;
}
```